# How to make CSS and JS both load in the footer

Tags: 8, theming

We have a library `slick_carousel` in our `mytheme.info.yml` and `mytheme.libraries.yml` defined in our sub-theme (see below).

How can we make the CSS and JS **both** load in the footer? Currently only the JS file is showing in the footer.

Current `mytheme.libraries.yml`:

```
slick_carousel:
  css:
    theme:
      //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css: { type: external, attributes: { async: true } }
  js:
    //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js: { type: external, minified: true  }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

We have tried, but didn't work. We need to do this without a module.

1. Removing dependency on `core/jquery`.
2. Change `theme` to `component` under `css`.

Answer (score -2):

You can just add 'scope' option and pass either 'header' or 'footer' as the value.

```
slick_carousel:
  css:
    theme:
      slick.min.css: { type: external, attributes: { aysnc: true }, scope:footer }
  js:
    slick.min.js: { type: external, minified: true, scope: footer }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Comment: are you sure that is the right syntax? According to this `https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module`, attributes is supposed `, attributes: { aysnc: true },`

Comment: That's correct. I missed that part. It should be, attributes: { async: true }. I have updated the example.

Comment: can you update your answer so others see it? Also, this does not work. The slick.min.css still shows up in the `<head>`, the `slick.min.js` file does show up in the footer as expected, but that is true whether I supply the scope attribute or not.

Comment: `scope` is deprecated. All JS loads in the footer by default. To load CSS in the footer you'd need to load if from `html.html.twig` on the theming level. But it's maybe better to just don't do that and simply load it as usual via YAML.

Comment: @leymannx that explains why `scope` wasn't working.